# gparted unallocated entire hard drive

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

Here is my whole situation: I have a dual booted Windows/Ubuntu computer. In order to move from space from the Ubuntu partition onto the Windows partition, I booted into a live Ubuntu 10.10 CD and asked gparted to make my Ubuntu partition about thirty gigabytes smaller, and then move it about thirty gigabytes to the right. Somewhere during the moving operation, gparted gave me an error, and now reports my entire hard drive as unallocated.

On information about the partition, gparted tells me that the first sector is zero, the last sector is xxxxxxx625 and total sectors is xxxxxxxx626. It gives a warning that you cannot have a partition outside the disk.

It also told me, at some point, that I had an invalid partition table.

Output of fdisk -l

```
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6
Warning: ignoring extra data in partition table 6

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sda: 640.1 GB, 640135028736 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 77825 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x903c57bc

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1744    14005248   27  Unknown
/dev/sda2   *        1744        1757      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda3            1757       10879    73276090    7  HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sda4           10879       77826   537746433    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           10879       72532   495228202   83  Linux
/dev/sda6   ?      140303      150988    85825552   6b  Unknown
```

I'd like to get my partitions back to working order. I have backups of most of my important data, but it would still be good to locate where my information went. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit/Update:**

Running test disk to find and restore a partition table, and then running boot-repair, I was able to make the Windows partition bootable and it now works fine. However, gparted still shows the entire disk as unallocated, and I'm incabable of booting into Linux, although I can still look at some files using utilities like TestDisk, and can see the partitions with fdisk. Reccomendations still appreciated

Comment: update: running test disk to find and restore a partition table, and then running boot-repair, I was able to make the windows partition bootable, and it now works fine. however, gparted still shows the entire disk as unallocated, and I'm incabable of booting into linux, although I can still look at some files using utilities like TestDisk, and can see the partitions with fdisk.
reccomendations still appreciated